# Python SubProcess OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm trying out a small Python program to encrypt and decrypt a zip file using 7 zip and here is the script:

```
import zipfile
import os
import subprocess

os.environ['ZIP_ENCRYPT_PASS'] = 'test'
password = os.environ['ZIP_ENCRYPT_PASS']

# Step 1: Encrypt the file using AES256
rc = subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', '-mem=AES256', password, '-y', 'myarchive.zip'] + 
                     ['/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/test.txt', '/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/some.txt'])


# Step 2: Decrypt the archive
f = zipfile.ZipFile('myarchive.zip').extractall(pwd=password)
```

When I tried to run this script, I get an error message as below:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:python-projects joe$ python ./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 10, in <module>
    ['/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/test.txt', '/Users/joe/Projects/Sandbox/python-projects/some.txt'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried to run this script like:

```
python test.py

python ./test.py
```

Both the approaches landed me with the same error message! Both the files that I'm trying to zip exists and I have even given full permissions on those files!

Is there anything that I'm missing and how to get rid of this annoying error?

Comment: Could you try giving the abspath of `7z` to subprocess `call` ? `/usr/bin/7z` ?

Comment: How can I add that as a dependency in Python?

Comment: How can you add `what` as a `dependency` ?

Comment: I don't want to use 7z from the underlying OS, but rather I want that as a library that I can run anywhere!

Comment: Unless the program is in the default `PATH`, it won't be able to find it

Comment: So that means I have to have 7 zip installed if I want to run my script? My question was - Is there a Python dependency for 7 zip that I can install when I run the script?

Comment: I do not know much about `7z` other than what i read from your question